# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

there are two sample here,

1.

in controller

```
 $result_article = $this->cms->get_content($event_id);
 if($result_article->num_rows() == 1){
 $data['row'] = $result_article->row();
}
```

in my view

```
<?php echo $row->title; ?>
```

print_r($row)/print_r($result_article->row()); output

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 43 [title] => Grant visit by Prime Minister [content] => this is the content [create_date] => 2012-09-21 [last_update] => 2012-09-22 19:27:12 )
```

with error appeared

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
Filename: libraries/Parser.php
Line Number: 101
```

2.

in controller

```
$result_article = $this->cms->get_content($event_id);

                    if($result_article->num_rows() == 1){
                        $row = $result_article->row();

                          $data = array(
                             'title' => $row->title
                          );
}
```

in my view

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

print_r($title) output

```
Grant visit by Prime Minister
```

no error.

what is the different between the 1st controller and 2nd code, it suppose to be the same output right? i am confused！

to make it more clear, i have simplified the code

here is the model

```
function get_content($event_id){
     $this->db->select('id,title,content,create_date,last_update');
     $query = $this->db->get_where('events',array('id' => $event_id));
     return $query;
}
```

the controller

```
$data['query']  = $this->cms->get_content($this->uri->segment(3));

if($data['query']->num_rows() == 1){
$row = $data['query']->row();

<!--with this code, no error appear-->
$data = array(
'title' => $row->title,
'content' => $row->content,
'create_date' => $row->create_date,
'last_update' => $row->last_update,
'event_id' => $row->id
              );
<!--with this code, no error appear-->
```

if is only these code

```
$data['query']  = $this->cms->get_content($this->uri->segment(3));

    if($data['query']->num_rows() == 1){
    $row = $data['query']->row();
```

error happen,

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string
Filename: libraries/Parser.php
Line Number: 101
```

Comment: Yes, please accept some answers. Then, give us the output of this: `print_r($result_article->row());`

Comment: i have edited my ans and included the print_r output.

Answer (score 1):

In your view in situation 1 it should be

```
<?php echo $article->row->title; ?>
```

to make the code the same as in situation 2.

As I see it, $article is a collection of rows, so you have to access a row from a article, and then get the title of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Try to serialize() the 'row' before gettin the title. Because your query, I guess, returns a xml format (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

For those that have this issue, replace in \system\libraries\Parser.php:

```
$template = $this->_parse_single($key, (string)$val, $template);
```

To:

```
if (!is_object($val)) $template = $this->_parse_single($key, (string)$val, $template);
```